# DevExpress ChartXtras... I have multiple panes on a chart... but want just one scroll bar

Tags: winforms, charts, devexpress

In DevExpress charts on Winforms I have multiple panes on a chart and it's working beautifully.

However, all three panes each have a Y Axis label and a horizontal scroll bar... they do keep in sync with one another... but I really only need one.

I figured out how to turn off the Y Axis in two of the panes by using:

```
diagram.AxisX.SetVisibilityInPane(false, volumeView.Pane);
diagram.AxisX.SetVisibilityInPane(false, exchangeRateView.Pane);
```

Is there some similar technique I can use to turn off the visibility of the scroll bar in two of my panes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize the appearance of a pane's scroll bars, use the [XYDiagramPaneBase.ScrollBarOptions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsXYDiagramPaneBase_ScrollBarOptionstopic) property. To manage the visibility of the X-axis scroll bar you can use the [ScrollBarOptions.XAxisScrollBarVisible](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsScrollBarOptions_XAxisScrollBarVisibletopic) property;